# What exactly does getSubimage() of BufferedImage do?

Tags: java, drawing, bufferedimage

I'm working on a 'drawing' application. The entire 'drawing' is constantly stored in a `BufferedImage` object (using a constant update loop). Let's call it `drawingArea`.

I'm implementing a selection tool, using the `BufferedImage` class' `getSubimage()` method. The user uses this tool to select an area of the drawing, and paste it anywhere on the drawing.

The user selects an area by dragging the mouse, and when he/she releases the mouse, the selected area is stored in a `BufferedImage`. This is done by calling `drawingArea`'s `getSubimage( /* properties of the selected rectangular area */ )` method, and putting the returned value inside that `BufferedImage` (let's call it `selectedArea`).

This operation is done **only once** (aka, **once there's a value inside `selectedArea`, there isn't any code that assigns anything new to `selectedArea`**).

However, I found out (and am certain of it), that the value stored in `selectedArea` does change - the image it stores gets updated!

Meaning: If the user selects an area (at this point an image which is a copy of this area is saved), **then** draws something **inside that area**, and **then** pastes the picture - the picture pasted would be the one **after** the drawing, and not before it.

How can this be? Does `getSubimage()` return a `BufferedImage` that gets updated when it's origin is updated? (aka the area that it was copied from)?
This seems silly but at this point it seems to me like the only option.

Comment: Sorry, I was wrong. 1+ to your question.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Seriously? And I thought this questions was dumb :D :)

Comment: Serious as a heart attack. Thanks for teaching me something new!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When in doubt, check the documentation:

> Returns a subimage defined by a specified rectangular region. *The returned BufferedImage shares the same data array as the original image.*

In other words, yes, modification in either the original or the sub image is seen in the other.

Comment: I'll be damned -- I'm wrong. 1+ for doing the right thing!

Comment: Lol and I thought that this was a dumb question. Been looking for the bug for hours, great to know it's not a bug with my code. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Joni - Thanks for answering my question. 'Sharing the same data array', practically means that the two BufferedImage objects are identical in everyway, is this correct?

Comment: @Prog, Joni, Hovercraft: There's also a potential resource leak hidden in this "shares the same data array". If you crop, even the tiniest portion of a huge image, the entire huge image is kept in memory, because the sub image keeps a live reference to the huge image's backing array...